# Making games in iPhone which one i use

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I have made some apps on iPhone but now want to try my hand on games....for this i searched and found some useful tools....

- Cosco 2d
- sparrow
- openGL

i want to start using any one of them...but do not know which should be easy one....to start....help required!
If you know about any other easy tools please provide info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about the sparrow...

but if you want to make board game or 2d game like mario contra chess etc cocos 2d is better option as it has native support of 2d animation sprites and transition

but if you want to make 3d game like doom warcraft counter strike etc open gl is better option as The interface consists of over 250 different function calls which can be used to draw complex three-dimensional scenes from simple primitives. and it is easy to implement virtual realty type games in it.

Comment: ok ...now i want to learn OpenGL.. but is it easy enough for a learner to start with it..

Comment: as far as you have some programming experience it can be learned... there are may wrappers/Engine available which is built on OpenGL which makes your task simple. One Example is SDL

Answer (score 2):

The proper graphics library depends heavily on what you want to make, so some more info would be great. ;)

As mihirpmehta mentioned, OpenGL can do 3D graphics and has a good few features. Not mentioned is that it is easily capable of doing "2D" graphics as well, although it may be more awkward to do 2D in OpenGL as opposed to one of the others.

You should figure out exactly what you want to do, then go through any documentation (and tutorials) on the various libraries. Pick the one that seems to fit your needs best, but keep an eye toward stability, speed, etc.